# Showing the 10 first prime Fibonacci numbers in python

Tags: python, runtime-error, fibonacci

There is a problem we need to solve in my university where we need to print the 10 smallest prime fibonacci numbers in an ascending order.So far i have found this code but it takes about 2 min to print them and was wondering if there was a faster way to print them.

```
import math


def isSquare(n):
    sr = (int)(math.sqrt(n))
    return (sr * sr == n)


def printPrimeAndFib(n):
    prime = [True] * (n + 1)
    p = 2
    while (p * p <= n):
        if (prime[p] == True):
            for i in range(p * 2, n + 1, p):
                prime[i] = False
        p = p + 1
    list=[]
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        if (prime[i] and (isSquare(5 * i * i + 4) > 0 or
                          isSquare(5 * i * i - 4) > 0)):
            list.append(i)
    print(list)


n = 500000000
printPrimeAndFib(n)
```

Comment: Please provide the error message you recived. Also, in python, we do `int(math.sqrt(n))` and not `(int)(math.sqrt(n))`

Comment: This needs to be run via coderunner and it just shows that i failed one or more hidden tests even though when i run it on PyCharm it displays the numbers which are

[2, 3, 5, 13, 89, 233, 1597, 28657, 514229, 433494437]

Comment: You are generating each and every natural number, then testing if each is prime and Fibonacii. It would be far faster to generate the Fibonacci number directly (which involves only addition and skips most natural numbers), then test each for primality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach generates Fibonacci numbers until it finds 10 that are prime; takes approx 0.001-0.002 seconds

```
from math import sqrt

def isprime(x):

    #deal with prime special cases 1 and 2
    if x==2:
        return True
    if x == 1 or x%2==0:
        return False

    #Fast-ish prime checking - only scan odds numbers up to sqrt(x)    
    for n in range(3,int(sqrt(x))+1,2):
        if x%n==0:
            return False

    return True

fib_primes = []
current=1
previous=1

while (len(fib_primes)<10):

    if isprime(current):
        fib_primes.append(current)
      

    next = current+previous
    previous = current
    current = next

print(fib_primes)
```

Answer (score 1):

With a Fibonacci generator and a prime filter. Takes about 0.002 seconds.

```
from itertools import islice
from math import isqrt

def fibonacci():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

def is_prime(n):
    return n > 1 and all(map(n.__mod__, range(2, isqrt(n) + 1)))

fibonacci_primes = filter(is_prime, fibonacci())
print(list(islice(fibonacci_primes, 10)))
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 5, 13, 89, 233, 1597, 28657, 514229, 433494437]
```

Comment: Take a look at [`operator.mod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.mod) (can replace `n.__mod__`)

Comment: @RoyCohen And use it how? With `functools.partial`? Easier to just use the existing method that does exactly what we need.

Comment: On second thought, I think the best and most readable way would just be `all(n % i != 0 for i in range(2, isqrt(n) + 1))`

Comment: Meh, readability is subjective, and I can read mine perfectly fine :-). Fewer tokens and characters than yours. Why do you think that one is "best"?

Comment: I think mine is more readable than all this one-line rubbish /s.  but then again, when I learned to code you had to give every line a number so what do I know!

Comment: In my opinion, it's the most readable because it's the simplest and it doesn't rely on any 'tricks'. But as you said, readability is subjective.

Comment: @JeffUK Hmm, how long ago was that? I think I started with GW-BASIC and had to give every line a number there as well, but I'm sure it wasn't true for all languages at that time.

Comment: @RoyCohen Ok but why "best"? You said "best and most readable", so that's two things.

Comment: @RoyCohen Not sure what you're calling "tricks" here, btw. I do like to come up with tricks, but I don't think I have any here.